Is this ring isomorphic to a quotient of a group algebra?
Consider the quotient of the free algebra $\mathbb{Q}\langle \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \varepsilon, \zeta \rangle$ by the two-sided ideal $I$ subject to the relations $$ \alpha\delta=\delta\alpha=0,\qquad \beta\varepsilon=\varepsilon\beta=0,\qquad \gamma\zeta=\zeta\gamma=0$$ and $$\alpha\varepsilon+\beta\delta=\varepsilon\alpha+\delta\beta=1, \quad \beta\zeta+\gamma\varepsilon=\zeta\beta+\varepsilon\gamma=1, \quad \gamma\delta+\alpha\zeta=\delta\gamma+\zeta\alpha=1.$$
I need to know, can this quotient be isomorphic to some quotient of a $\mathbb{Q}$-group algebra?
More specifically, does there exist a group $G$ and an ideal $J \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[G]$
such that $$\mathbb{Q}\langle \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \varepsilon, \zeta \rangle/ I \cong \mathbb{Q}[G]/J$$ as algebras?

What is the context? What do you know about the two and four variable cases?

If $A$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, then there is a group $G$ such that $A$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ if and only if $A$ is generated by units. For the "if" direction, take $G$ to be the group of units.
For the algebra in the OP, the relations imply that
$$(\alpha+\beta)(\delta+\varepsilon)=1=(\delta+\varepsilon)(\alpha+\beta),$$
so $\alpha+\beta$ and $\delta+\varepsilon$ are units.
Similarly, $\beta+\gamma$, $\varepsilon+\zeta$, $\gamma+\alpha$ and $\zeta+\delta$ are units.
So
$$\alpha=\frac{1}{2}\left((\alpha+\beta)-(\beta+\gamma)+(\gamma+\alpha)\right)$$
is in the subalgebra generated by units. Similarly, so are $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$, $\varepsilon$ and $\zeta$, and so the algebra is generated by units, and therefore is a quotient of a group algebra.

That is a great answer, and shows how to attack all such problems.

It's easy to modify the argument to show that a finitely-generated $\mathbb Q$-algebra is a quotient of $\mathbb Q[G]$ for a finitely-generated group $G$ if and only if $A$ is generated by units (take a finite generating set of $A$, and express those in terms of units, to find finitely many units that generate $A$, and then take the group generated by those units).

Thank you very much. Do you know a reference for this theorem?

@Bumblebee Sorry, no, I don't think I've seen it before. But I'd call it an observation rather than a theorem.
